# matplotlib fails with dateutil

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pybrain

I believe I installed matplotlib correctly with 2.7:

```
$ pip install matplotlib
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): matplotlib in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): tornado in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyparsing>=1.5.6,!=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): nose in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil->matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): backports.ssl-match-hostname in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tornado->matplotlib)
Cleaning up...
```

However I get the following error when I run an example with it:

```
 python rl.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rl.py", line 21, in <module>
    import pylab
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/pylab.py", line 221, in <module>
    from matplotlib import mpl  # pulls in most modules
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/mpl.py", line 3, in <module>
    from matplotlib import axes
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axes.py", line 19, in <module>
    import matplotlib.dates as mdates
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/dates.py", line 119, in <module>
    from dateutil.rrule import rrule, MO, TU, WE, TH, FR, SA, SU, YEARLY, \
ImportError: No module named dateutil.rrule
```

Comment: Firstly in your python code try to import `dateutil` and then (if successful) do `print(dateutil.__file__)` and check that it is the same file as given in the pip output.

Comment: @Ffisegydd I think it's trying to use the package in the System location, even though I've installed python via homebrew and using it